# modification of the Ramsey number

Tags: combinatorics

This was a question on my exam which I was struggling with:

> Show that there is a number $T(a,b)$ for given positive integers $a,b$, such that for any set $N$ with $|N|\ge T(a,b)$ and any subset $E\subseteq \{h\subseteq N: |h|=3\}$, at least one of the following is true:
>   -There is a subset $X\subseteq N,|X|\ge a$ such that $\{h\subseteq X: |h|=3\}\subseteq E$
>   -There is a subset $Y\subseteq N,|Y|\ge b$ such that $\{h\subseteq Y: |h|=3\}\cap E=\emptyset$.

My idea was to color all the 3-subsets of $E$ red. Then the Ramsey number $R(3,a,b)$ says there is a subset that contains $a$ red 3-subsets, or $b$ blue ones. From this the claim follow. But this seems way to easy and I'm pretty sure my reasoning is wrong, I don't see where though.

Comment: Perhaps they want you to prove it?

Comment: Obviously...this is where I'm having problems. I don't know if I misunderstood the question, because my "proof" seems to straightforward and easy to be correct.

Comment: What you sketched was not a proof; you just identified (correctly) that this is a special case of Ramsey's theorem. Perhaps they want you to prove it. There is not really enough detail in the question to tell otherwise. What exam is this? What kind of students take it?

Comment: If you mean proving Ramsey's theorem, then no, it can be assumed to be true. I'll try to put some more details: Let $|N|\ge R(3,a,b)$, where $R$ is Ramsey's number. Color all 3-subsets of $E$ red, the rest of the 3-subsets of $N$ blue. Then the Ramsey property gives us either a subset $X$ with $a$ elements, whose 3-subsets are all red, or a subset $Y$ with $b$ elements, whose 3-subsets are all blue. So either every 3-subset of $X$ is contained in $E$ (since they are red), or $Y$ has all blue 3-subsets, so the intersection with the 3-subsets of $E$ is empty.

Comment: @bls this is ramsey numbers of dimension 3 and two colors, I prove they exist in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Ramsey's theorem for $2$ colors and hypergraphs of dimension $3$ the existence of Ramsey's theorem for $2$ colors and dimension $n\geq3$ can be proven using induction. I will just prove the step from $n=2$ to $n=3$ but it can be easily modified. $R(a,b)$ is just the usual Ramsey number on two colors and dimension $2$.The $3-$subsets of color 1 are those pertaining to $E$ and the $3-$subsets of color $2$ are those not pertaining to $E$

The claim is that $R_3(a,b)\leq R(R_3(a-1,b),R_3(a,b-1))+1$

The proof is by dividing in two cases, each of which has two subcases. notice that a vertex $v$ has $R(R_3(a-1,b),R_3(a,b-1))$ neighbors. We color the edge $uw$ blue if the triangle $uvw$ is blue and red if triangle $uvw$ is red. Since $v$ has $R(R_3(a-1,b),R_3(a,b-1))$ neigbors, its neighbors must make a red complete graph of size $R_3(a-1,b)$ or a blue complete graph of size $R_3(a,b-1)$.

Case 1: the neighbors of $v$ make a red complete graph of size $R_3(a-1,b)$. Then there are two cases: that complete graph contains a subsetset of size $a-1$ with only red triangles inside it. If this happens, since all of the edges are red, we can add vertex $v$ and all triangles of the new set will also be red, this set has size $a$. The other case is that the complete graph has a subset of size $b$ with only blue triangles, but this also satisfies the problem.

Case 2: the neighbors of $v$ make a complete blue graph of size $R_3(a,b-1)$. Then there are two cases: that complete graph contains a subsetset of size $a$ with only red triangles inside it. or it contains a subset of size $b-1$ with only blue triangles, but in this case we can add $v$ and since all the edges of that complete graph are blue, so are all the triangles with $v$. So we now have a subset of size $b$ containing only blue triangles.

This completes the proof.